# Using Ebay SDK API: ExcludeShipToLocation.Add("CN") causes:“Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I've been trying to figure out how to exclude some locations using Ebay API Csharp but so far I haven't solved this after so many code variations and deep-googling.

I need help in excluding "China".

```
item.ShippingDetails.ExcludeShipToLocation = new StringCollection();
```

But when the program hits this line of code, this error shows up:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

If you would like to see the full code here it is:

```
using eBay.Service.Call;
using eBay.Service.Core.Sdk;
using eBay.Service.Core.Soap;
using eBay.Service.Util;
using Samples.Helper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ebayapiex3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApiContext context = AppSettingHelper.GetApiContext();

            context.ApiLogManager = new ApiLogManager();
            context.ApiLogManager.ApiLoggerList.Add(new FileLogger("log.txt", true, true, true));
            context.ApiLogManager.EnableLogging = true;
            context.Site = SiteCodeType.US;

            ReviseFixedPriceItemCall reviseFP = new ReviseFixedPriceItemCall(context);

            ItemType item = new ItemType();

            item.ItemID = "************";

            item.Title = "TITLE HAS BEEN CHANGED";

            item.Quantity = 99;

            item.StartPrice = new AmountType();

            item.StartPrice.Value = 795.76;

            item.ShipToLocations = new StringCollection();
            item.ShipToLocations.Add("US");
            item.ShipToLocations.Add("AU");

            item.ShippingDetails.ExcludeShipToLocation = new StringCollection();
            item.ShippingDetails.ExcludeShipToLocation.Add("CN");

            reviseFP.Item = item;

            reviseFP.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine(reviseFP.ApiResponse.Ack + " SKU " + reviseFP.SKU);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `item.ShippingDetails` before assiging to its members.

```
item.ShippingDetails = new ShippingDetailsType();
item.ShippingDetails.ExcludeShipToLocation = new StringCollection();
item.ShippingDetails.ExcludeShipToLocation.Add("CN");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now it says: "Error: The type or namespace name 'ShippingDetails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I checked documentation, and corrected version is in answer above, change `ShippingDetails()` to `ShippingDetailsType()`.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiException: The email address you e
ntered isn't linked to a PayPal account. If you don't have a PayPal account, you
'll need to set one up with this address so that buyers can pay you. (You can se
t up your account after your item sells).
At least one valid shipping service must be specified.
At least one valid shipping service must be specified.
   at eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiCall.SendRequest()
   at eBay.Service.Call.ReviseFixedPriceItemCall.Execute()
   at ebayapiex3.Program.Main(String[] args)